# jquery statement to focus on live generated input

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, focus

Okay, so I need for an input element to be automatically focused when it shows up in the DOM. This is what I am currently trying to do:

```
modal.fadeIn('fast', function(){
    $('input.cm_modal_input_elem').focus();
});
```

This isn't working. What is the official way to do this?

Comment: have you put this code inside a $(document).ready function, to make sure the DOM is ready before it gets executed?

Comment: @PeterVr yah I learned that a long time ago. But thats always a good start. (short answer: yes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the official way of doing it, and if it's not working something else besides the posted code must be causing the problem. Like say you are inserting the element dynamically and expecting a function you called on page load to execute later on when the element is inserted or that there are other elements that receive focus later in your script etc.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uX6e/) to show it working !

Comment: The funny part is when I type in line 2 into Chrome's JavaScript console (while the input is attached to the DOM), it will return the exact input element without focusing it.